# Javascript | Search in an array of JSON by JSONs specific key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, indexing

I need search in an array of JSON objects if a key with especific id value exists. If exists, return it, if not return -1 or whatever

```
var array = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'xxx'},
             {'id': 2, 'name': 'yyy'},
             {'id': 3, 'name': 'zzz'}];

var searchValue --> id==1
```

---

should be something like this?

```
function search_array(array,valuetofind) {
 if array.indexof({'id': valuetofind}) != -1 {
  return array[array.indexof({'id': valuetofind})]  
 } else {
  return {'id': -1}
 }
}
```

Comment: nope, because `{'id': valuetofind}` creates a new object literal which is distinct from every other object. (even if it wasn't, still it wouldn't equal the objects in the array because it lacks other keys.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This returns the object if a match exists and -1 if there's no match.

```
function search_array(array,valuetofind) {
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i]['id'] === valuetofind) {
            return array[i];
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need to make sure the id exists try this:

```
function search_array(array, valuetofind) {
    var exists = false;
    for(i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
        if(array[i].id == valuetofind) {
            exists = true;
        }
    }
    return exists;
}
```

My method may be a little long winded cycling through each part but i checked and it works

```
search_array(array, 4) [False]
search_array(array, 1) [True]
```

Comment: From condition "If exists, return it,"

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
search(nameKey, myArray){
    for (var i=0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        if (myArray[i].name === nameKey) {
              return myArray[i];
         }
    }
}
var array = [
   { name:"string 1", value:"this", other: "that" },
   { name:"string 2", value:"this", other: "that" }
];

var resultObject = search("string 1", array);
```